# Correct syntax for replacement of deprecated "sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, deprecated

I have had exactly 10 days of iOS/Objective-C training (and pretty much no other coding classes) and am thus way out of my league on this, but I inherited a huge iOS app at work for which I am now responsible for upgrading from iOS6-centric to iOS 7-centric. I'm trying to clean up all of the warnings in Xcode and simply cannot figure this one out. I've searched for days and read every answer here on SO, but none exactly answers my question (though some have helped me get closer, for which I am truly grateful).

I know that "sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:" is deprecated and needs to be replaced with "boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:", but for the life of me I can't figure out how to convert some existing code from the old method to the new. If I can get this one straightened out it will clear up 35 other warnings in Xcode, as that same deprecated method is used in numerous other places.

The research I've done yields a few examples of how the new method is used, but it appears it is used in different ways (CGRect and CGSize) and Apple's documentation just sends me in "one infinite loop". For my "options:", Apple says to use paragraph style options, yet those are completely different than what was available for the deprecated style (half of those are deprecated, too). For example, they say if you don't specify a style, it will use the default paragraph style, but I don't know what attributes those are or really where to find them to verify what they are. If I DO specify a style, it has to be "this one" or "that one", but then if I use one of those I have to also use "this other one", however none of those will take effect unless my line break mode is "yet another one", but the "yet another one" style isn't the one I need to use.

So, I can't figure out how to specifically translate the attributes I have in the old code into code that will yield the exact same results in the non-deprecated method. I think I'm pretty close, but can't get the correct use of "NSLineBreakByClipping" to translate into the new method's syntax without getting a hard error. The error is in the line "width=expectedLabelSize1.width" and says "No member named "width" in 'struct CGRect' ". If I change the CGRect so CGSize, like it was in the original code, I get a different error on that specific line about initializing an expression with an incompatible type.

Here is the original code:

```
        int width = 0;
    if([surveyType isEqualToString:@"Site Survey"]){

//calculate the expected width of the survey label...
        CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(165,16);
        CGSize expectedLabelSize1 = [surveyName sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:9.0] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];
        width=expectedLabelSize1.width;
        if(width > 165){
            width=165;
        }
```

And here is what I've been able to cobble together instead:

```
//calculate the expected width of the survey label...
        CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(165,16);
        CGRect expectedLabelSize1 = [surveyName boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize
                                                  options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin |
                                                           NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine | NSLineBreakByWordWrapping)
                                               attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:9.0]}
                                                  context:nil];

        width=expectedLabelSize1.width;
        if(width > 165){
            width=165;
        }
```

I don't really know what I'm doing here, obviously, so I'm hoping someone can show me how to convert the old method to the new and not lose any of the functionality or formatting in the process. How can I incorporate the NSLineBreakModeByClipping attribute I originally had if that no longer appears to be a available attribute or option?

THANK YOU!!!

EDIT: I apologize, but I just realized that I left out some code that may help explain one of the errors I was getting. I left out the very first two lines above, where the variable "width" is initialized as an integer. This whole "label size calculation" code is part of a much larger "if" statement, but the only part giving me fits is the deprecated method to which this post pertains. Anyway, since "width" is not addressed in the CGRect, the very next line after the CGRect method (width=expectedLabelSize1.width) generates the error above about "width" not being a member of the struct. I get that, now, but I don't know how to add the "width" attribute to the CGRect struct. The overall method (boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:) as I have it appears to be "clean", in that it doesn't generate any errors on its own, but it doesn't address "width" or NSLineBreakModeByClipping. That's where I'm getting an error (for the missing "width" variable) and where I'm getting lost on exactly how to incorporate NSLineBreakModeByClipping into the new method syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to use UILabel sizeThatFits

eg.

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX,16);
CGSize expectedLabelSize1 = [surveyName sizeThatFits:max];
width=expectedLabelSize1.width;
if(width > 165){
  width=165;
}
```

Also see http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/07/youre-doing-it-wrong-2-sizing-labels.html

Comment: This works great if you're in a method like `layoutSubviews`. If you're in a class/static method then it's cleanest to use `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`.

Comment: Thanks, railwayparade, but using this method doesn't work in this case. The "surveyName" object in the code is an NSString object. I get an error that "No visible @interface for NSString declares the selector sizeThatFits:". From what I can dig up, that means that the method is not part of the NSString class and thus can't be used. The "label" this code is generating is a text label on the cover page of a PDF, not a button on the UI. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I perform my text sizing these days:

```
- (CGSize)textSizeWithBoundingWidth:(CGFloat)boundingWidth attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
{
    CGSize boundingSize = (CGSize){.width = boundingWidth,.height = 0};
    NSStringDrawingOptions options = (NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine);
    CGRect textBoundingRect = [self boundingRectWithSize:boundingSize options:options attributes:attributes context:nil];

    return ((CGSize){.width = CGRectGetMaxX(rect),.height = CGRectGetMaxY(rect)})
}
```

You will also need to pass in a dictionary of text attributes. For the two you want (font and lineBreakMode), you can pass them in like so:

```
NSMutableDictionary* attributesDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[attributesDictionary setObject:self.font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
[style setLineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode];

[attributesDictionary setObject:style forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
```